# Google Earth has a screen glitch, and copies the background

Tags: screen, deb, google, google-earth

I installed google earth, using the 32bit *google-earth-pro.deb* for linux from google's website.
Since then, however, I've had a repeating error: Whenever I open google earth, the it *copies my background screen* and shows that, instead of the normal google earth map:

[image: The screenshot]

As you can see, the normal map is just in one tiny corner. What could be causing this?

Comment: If you start `gedit`, is the editing window also transparent? Do you have "low graphics mode" set in Compiz?

Comment: Sometimes yes, actually. It goes away after about 10 seconds, or so.

Comment: Is this a common system error?

Comment: Just a hunch. Try deleting the .xinputrc file. `rm -i .xinputrc` let me know if that fixes the problem, and I'll write an answer that you can accept, ok?

Comment: It wasn't there: `rm: cannot remove '.xinputrc': No such file or directory`

Comment: Let me try a slight variation of the command... `rm -i ~/.xinputrc`. No space between / and . Also, see if Google Earth acts the same way if you log into a different account.

Comment: Nope, still the same: `rm: cannot remove '/home/jason/.xinputrc': No such file or directory`. And I don't log into google earth.

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you log into a different user account? You could try the 64bit version https://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html

Comment: I tried both the 32 and 64 bit versions, and the 32bit didn't start at all.

Comment: You've confused me. The first sentence in your question says that you were using 32-bit. And what about using another user account?

Comment: Crap, I was wrong, the 64bit didn't start at all. And I only have one account on my computer.