# Google Earth does not show any map

Tags: google-earth

I have the same problem as is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956464/google-earth-has-a-screen-glitch-and-copies-the-background) but that question does not have an answer and its OP does not seem like they will ever answer the arisen questions.

I installed `google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb` via `sudo apt install` on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

Deleting `~/.xinputrc` did not change anything. When I log into a different account (account on my machine, that is – I do not think the commenter meant a different Google account (I did not log into any Google account)), I experience the exact same problem.

It is not like a glitch which occurs for a few seconds and then vanishes. Google Earth just is not usable because the map never shows up. It always **shows** the controls, part of the splash screen, and **whatever was in the background** when the application was launched.

[image: What shows up when I launch Google Earth:]

[`ttf-mscorefonts-installer` already was installed.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40156/weird-looking-google-earth)

[Using `gdebi` didn't resolve the problem either.](https://askubuntu.com/a/431014/195768)

[Neither did using the 32 bit version.](https://askubuntu.com/a/136548/195768)

Comment: Having installed the ``.deb`` from Google, I've also tried the Safe mode graphics, to no avail.

Comment: Also, this seems to be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/956464/58950 which, although it might appear as abandoned, it's only one month old.

Comment: @carnendil I linked to that question in the very first paragraph. I did, however, not see that it's "only" abandoned for a month but a year. Somehow, I read the date as "September 2016", not "September the 16th".

Comment: I also thought it was "September 2016" the first time :). That's why I made the "duplicate" comment only later. I haven't found a solution to question yet.

Comment: @UTF-8 , I am experiencing the same problem, even installing the 32-bit version didn't work. I was going to ask this as a separate question but found this question to be having exactly what I wanted to ask. If you've already found the solution by now please answer your own question, if not I am hopeful people viewing this will be able to find a solution to it soon.

Comment: @KewalShah Unfortunately, I was not able to come up with a solution.

Comment: I made a script that creates a Linux AppImage for Google Earth, using the latest working version. https://gist.github.com/jrmdev/48207c81afa1f8acc59f2bb16500dd67

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem:

Find the currently installed Google Earth package

```
dpkg --list 'google-earth*'
```

Uninstall the existing package:

```
sudo dpkg -P google-earth-stable
```

**Install the googleearth-package** package:

```
sudo apt-get install googleearth-package
```

Use the script to download the latest binary and **create a .deb package**:

```
make-googleearth-package --force
```

An example of the message you should get after executing the above command:

```
Description: Google Earth, a 3D map/planet viewer
 Package built with googleearth-package.
dpkg-deb: building package 'googleearth' in './googleearth_6.0.3.2197+1.2.0-1_amd64.deb'.
-----------------------------
Success!
You can now install the package with e.g:

sudo dpkg -i googleearth_6.0.3.2197+1.2.0-1_amd64.deb
-----------------------------
```

Install the .deb package as mentioned in the description:

```
sudo dpkg -i googleearth_6.0.3.2197+1.2.0-1_amd64.deb
```

In case any dependecy problems arise (which did in my case), use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will successfully install a compatible version of Google Earth for your system.

Here's how Google Earth now looks:

(As opposed to how it looked on my PC as shown in the question)

[image: How it should look now]

Note: This method worked for me, hope it works out for you as well :)

*(reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth)*

Comment: Is there a similar solution for the latest GE 7.3 release?

Comment: @s6hebern Not that I know of, sorry!

Comment: Google no longer publishes the installation file `http://dl.google.com/earth/client/current/GoogleEarthLinux.bin
` required by this script.

Comment: Currently (2019-06-11), the only way to make Google Earth Pro work in such case consists of uninstalling its newest version, then downloading `google-earth-pro-stable_7.1.8.3036-r0_amd64.deb` straight from Google's official repository (https://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/pool/main/g/google-earth-pro-stable/google-earth-pro-stable_7.1.8.3036-r0_amd64.deb) and finally installing it. If e.g. you have `gdebi`installed (`sudo apt-get install gdebi -y`) and you saved such DEB package in `/tmp`, just run `sudo gdebi -n /tmp/google-earth-pro-stable_7.1.8.3036-r0_amd64.deb` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

This disappearing map problem occurs on computers with Intel graphics running `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and Google Earth Pro versions that are more recent than `google-earth-pro-stable_7.1.8.3036-r0_amd64.deb`.

Make sure `xserver-xorg-video-intel` is installed:

```bsh
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

On (X)Ubuntu LTS 20.04, the problem can be resolved by editing the following file. Create it if it is not present.

```bsh
$ sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Add the [Direct Rendering Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure) `dri3` as a `"Module"` and append three evocation lines to the `"Device"` section. Leave other sections unchanged. If your `xorg.conf`
file happens to be empty, copy the whole lot.

```
Section "Module"
   Load "dri3"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Device0"
    Driver          "intel"
    Option          "Backlight"      "intel_backlight"

    # DRI 3 evocation lines below
    Option      "DRI"   "3"
    Option      "TripleBuffer" "true"
    Option      "TearFree"     "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen0"
    Monitor         "Monitor0"
    Device          "Device0"
EndSection
```

Do not forget to **reboot.** After rebooting, recent Google Earth Pro versions should work fine; including street view.

Comment: Thank you! I would never have run across that "is discouraged" on my own, and it fixed both Google Earth and 3D in my browser. The other answer didn't help at all, but this one is perfect.

Comment: Excellent answer. This worked for me (I opted for option 2). Thank you so much.

Comment: At least till 2019-06-11 you could still download `google-earth-pro-stable_7.1.8.3036-r0_amd64.deb` straight from Google's official repository: https://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/pool/main/g/google-earth-pro-stable/google-earth-pro-stable_7.1.8.3036-r0_amd64.deb

Comment: Another Option 2 caveat: I experienced annoying screen tearing and couldn't find a solution. Instead of removing the Intel driver, it's now enough to reconfigure it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing, you don't need to remove `xserver-xorg-video-intel` to run the latest Google Earth. Simply enable dri3 in your Intel graphics config:

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-graphics.conf** (create if needed):

```
Section "Module"
   Load "dri3"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"

   # Fixes Google Earth. Requires dri3 module:
   Option      "DRI"   "3"

   # OPTIONAL, but fixes screen tearing for me:
   Option      "TripleBuffer" "true"
   Option      "TearFree"     "true"
EndSection
```

**Restart.** Works on Ubuntu 18.04 + Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2).