# Options for uninstalling a package when apt and dpkg dont work?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall, google-earth

I had problems with Google Earth, so I followed this [link's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965853/google-earth-doesnt-show-map) recommendations, which had me installing the googleearth-package package. I'm new to Ubuntu, so mid installation I got cold feet (not really understanding what I was installing or whether doing it was safe) and aborted it here:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7
  gcc-8-base:i386 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libatomic1
  libc-dev-bin libc6:i386 libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libcom-err2:i386
  libdb5.3:i386 libfakeroot libffi6:i386 libgcc-7-dev libgcc1:i386
  libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
  libidn2-0:i386 libitm1 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
  liblsan0 libmpx2 libnettle6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libquadmath0
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386
  libstdc++-7-dev libtasn1-6:i386 libtsan0 libubsan0
  libunistring2:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 linux-libc-dev make
  manpages-dev zlib1g:i386
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc
  libstdc++6-7-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison
  gcc-doc gcc-7-multilib gcc-7-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg
  libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386 glibc-doc gnutls-bin:i386
  libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386
  | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal:i386 libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386
  libsasl2-modules-otp:i386 libsasl2-modules-sql:i386
  libstdc++-7-doc make-doc
Recommended packages:
  libgnutls26:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7
  gcc-8-base:i386 googleearth-package libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6:i386
  libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libcom-err2:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libfakeroot
  libffi6:i386 libgcc-7-dev libgcc1:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgnutls30:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
  libhogweed4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libidn2-0:i386 libitm1
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 liblsan0 libmpx2
  libnettle6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libquadmath0
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386
  libstdc++-7-dev libtasn1-6:i386 libtsan0 libubsan0
  libunistring2:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 linux-libc-dev make
  manpages-dev zlib1g:i386
0 upgraded, 58 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 146 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n  
Abort.
```

So my next step was to uninstall whatever did get installed before I aborted; so I did this:

```
sudo dpkg -P googleearth-package
```

And I got this:

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove googleearth-package which isn't installed
```

So I tried:

```
apt list 'googleearth*'
Listing... Done
googleearth-package/bionic,bionic 1.2.2 all
```

So then:

```
apt remove googleearth-package
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

And then I didn't know what else to do so I came for your help, please.

Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't look like you actually installed anything - what  does `apt list --installed 'googleearth-package'` or `apt-cache policy 'googleearth-package'` say?

Comment: It says: `Listing... Done` - but what about this: `googleearth-package/bionic,bionic 1.2.2 all` that I get with `apt list 'googleearth-package'`

Comment: Without the `--installed` flag, `apt list` will list packages that are *available* - not just those that are installed

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.  So if the dpkg is aborted it doesn't install anything? Is this a rule or it depends on something else? I apologize in advance for the low level questions, I'm really new to this.

Comment: Removing the package : `sudo apt remove googleearth-package`