# I've had horrible screen tearing for a long time. HELP!!!! Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.10

```
(base) pokemaniac00@Flor-Ubuntu:~$ inxi -F
System:
  Host: Flor-Ubuntu Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.34.3 Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Precision 5530 v: N/A 
  serial: <root required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0F8T29 v: X04 serial: <root required> UEFI: Dell 
  v: 1.11.2 date: 05/29/2019 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 3.5 Wh condition: 88.8/97.0 Wh (92%) 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-8850H bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 9216 KiB 
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4300 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 5: 801 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 9: 800 10: 802 11: 800 12: 800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GLM [Quadro P1000 Mobile] driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: intel resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-42-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9260 driver: iwlwifi 
  IF: wlp59s0 state: up mac: 14:4f:8a:d8:cb:9c 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 151.97 GiB (31.9%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: PM981 NVMe 512GB 
  size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 151.94 GiB (32.5%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 fan-2: 0 
Info:
  Processes: 322 Uptime: 9m Memory: 15.30 GiB used: 1.49 GiB (9.7%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.36
```

Comment: Maybe helpfull. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066722/intel-screen-tearing-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Which driver do you use for Nvidia? Do you use both it and Intel?

Comment: You could try using xfce desktop environment. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfwm4/+bug/1294600/comments/28

Answer (score 0):

**Intel cards**

1. Open the terminal
2. Install mesa-utils:

   **sudo apt-get install mesa-utils**
3. Create a specific directory:

   **sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/**
4. Enter these parameters:

   **echo -e 'Section "Device"\n Identifier "Intel Graphics"\n Driver "Intel"\n Option "AccelMethod" "sna"\n Option "TearFree" "true"\nEndSection' | sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf**

That's it. Reboot and it should be ok now.

If you wanna undo this procedure just enter in the terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```